# drawing rounded rect on imageContext using UIBeizerpath not working

Tags: ios6, core-graphics

I had a requirement  to draw a rounded rect while user touch is moving on iPad. 
Here is my code it is showing black color rounded rect while touch moving and selected color when touch is ended. Can any one please tell me the reason?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    [path setLineWidth:lineSize];
    [selectedColor setStroke];

    [drawImage drawInRect:rect]; // (3)
      [path fill];
  }

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    startPoint=p;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
      float x=startPoint.x;
        float y=startPoint.y;
        float z=p.x-startPoint.x;
        float a=p.y-startPoint.y;

        if (z<0 && a<0) {
            x=p.x;
            y=p.y;
            z=startPoint.x-p.x;
            a=startPoint.y-p.y;
        }
        else if (a<0)
        {
            x=startPoint.x;
            y=startPoint.y;
            z=p.x-startPoint.x;
            a=startPoint.y-p.y;
        }
        else if(z<0)
        {
            x=startPoint.x;
            y=startPoint.y;
            z=startPoint.x-p.x;
            a=p.y-startPoint.y;

        }

        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(x,y,z,a) cornerRadius:10.0];

        [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
       [self drawBitmap];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
  }

- (void)drawBitmap // (3)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
     [selectedColor setStroke];
   if (!drawImage) // first draw; paint background white by ...
    {
        UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds]; // enclosing bitmap by a rectangle defined by another UIBezierPath object
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];

        [rectpath fill]; // filling it with white
    }

    [drawImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
       [selectedColor setFill];
        [path fill];
          drawImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `initWithFrame` method to make background of the UIView white.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```